# Template matching multiple output files

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have an XSL document that outputs to html. I want to run a batch process, using a filelist.xml to perform this transform on multiple XML input documents, with corresponding html output files, as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" name="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//*:file">
<xsl:variable select="document(@url)" name="contents" />
<xsl:variable select="replace(@url,'[.]xml','.html')" name="newfile" />
Creating <xsl:value-of select="$newfile" />
<xsl:result-document href="{$newfile}" format="html">
 <html><body>
 Test run: <xsl:value-of select="$contents/testrun/@run" />
 </body></html>
</xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I then apply templates to each of these files, the same as if I was processing one single file?  ie:

```
<xsl:template match="guidance">
```

Where "guidance" is the root node of my source XML. This is incorrect as I would have to nest a template. What would be the correct approach to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If a document filelist.xml is the primary input document of your stylesheet then please show us a sample structure of that file. And if this file links to other files you want to process then also show us a sample of those files you want to process. Then show a sample of the output you want to create for each file. Currently I am not sure what the problem is. You can certainly put an `<xsl:template match="guidance">...</xsl:template>` into your stylesheet and then apply it with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="$contents/guidance"/>` inside of the `xsl:result-document`.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a natural and easy solution.

Comment: You might be experiencing problems with the "root rule": do note that this rule will match the root document of **any document**. So, instead of applying templates to `$contents` document root, use `$contents/node()`.

Comment: @martin honnen. Thanks - that seemed to do the trick in this instance: `<xsl:apply-templates select="$contents/guidance"/>`. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Where "guidance" is the root node of my source XML. This is incorrect as I would have to nest a template. What would be the correct approach to this problem?

There's nothing wrong with defining a template rule with xsl:template match="guidance". It just has to follow the usual XSLT principle that all template rules appear at the outermost (global) level. To invoke the template you do something like xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)/guidance".

If you want to make things more modular you can (a) put all the template rules for one document type in one stylesheet module, and/or (b) use a different mode for the template rules for each document type.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I then apply templates to each
>   of these files, the same as if I was
>   processing one single file?

**Use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$contents" mode="fileLevel"/>
```

and provide any necessary templates in `mode="filelevel"` to process a single file.